# Logs in Google App Engine Not Working

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am building a Java Google App using Google App Engine and I followed [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime#Logging) on how to use Logging.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is very simple. I am issuing a POST request to a servlet in the App Engine, and I just want to print out via the Logs to see if I'm getting the data correctly. There are no statements in the Logs at all, aside from the automatically generated one saying that a POST was received, but my debug statement is not there.

Am I missing something simple outside of these directions? I'm baffled why this isn't working.

Comment: How are you attempting to create log entries right now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably you use debug level during logging, but your logging.properties file has INFO level. Change it to DEBUG:

```
# Set the default logging level for all loggers to WARNING
.level = DEBUG
```

Comment: It's actually set to "warning" right now. When doing the actual logging in code I was doing info. I'll try the way you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the minimum log level set in the logging.properties file.

[AppEngine Logging](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime#Logging)

Comment: I linked to the _exact_ link you provided in my question... I followed those instructions.

Comment: Sorry I have trouble distinguishing the light grayish/blue text of links on this site and didn't notice it.

Comment: I agree its near impossible to distinguish. Thank you though.